# What is the maximum size of TIFF metadata?

Tags: metadata, tiff

Is there a maximum limit to the amount of metadata that can be incorporated in an individual field of TIFF file metadata?  I'd like to store a large text (up to a few MB) in the ImageDescription field.

Comment: For TIFF rev 6 the limit is 2^32 minus the offset at which the text is stored in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no specific maximum limit to the `ImageDescription` field, however, there's a maximum file size for the entire TIFF file. This maximum size is 4 GB. From the TIFF 6.0 spec:

> The largest possible TIFF file is 2**32 bytes in length.

This is due to the offsets in the file structure, stored as unsigned 32 bit integers.

Thus, the theoretical maximum size is that which @cgohlke points out in the comments (*"2^32 minus the offset"*), but most likely you want to keep it smaller, if you also intend to include pixel data...

Storing *"a few MB"* should not be a problem.