# Image saving with PIL throws corruption error for large file size

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm converting a large numpy array to tif (2.28G) with PIL, but I am getting a file corrupted error. I ran the exact same code with a smaller array before and it worked (1.7G). How can I go about and solve this problem?

edits:

- The numpy array I cannot convert has dtype ('uint8') and dimension
  (854715, 890, 3)
- I have 1960MB inactive memory and 40MB free memory

The code:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os

folder =  'dirname'

# read all file names from defined folder core_images into a 
Python list (collection of data)
images = os.listdir(folder) 
# list to collect UV stacked numpy array
combine_core_UV = []
for img_name in images:
    im = Image.open(folder+"/"+img_name, 'r')
    img = np.array(im)

    x = 330
    x2 = 1663
    x3 = 3240
    x4 = 4457
    x5 = 5830
    y = 1675
    w = 890 # x2 - x1
    h = 8997 # y2 - y1
    crop_img1 = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    crop_img2 = img[y:y+h, x2:x2+w]
    crop_img3 = img[y:y+h, x3:x3+w]
    crop_img4 = img[y:y+h, x4:x4+w]
    crop_img5 = img[y:y+h, x5:x5+w]
    combined_image =np.concatenate((crop_img1,crop_img2,crop_img3,crop_img4,crop_img5),axis=0)
    combine_core_UV.append(combined_image)
    
   "concatenate pieces vertically"
combined_image_UV = np.concatenate(combine_core_UV,axis=0)
# save image
im = Image.fromarray(combined_image_UV)
im.save("uv_stacked_image_"+folder+".tif")
```

[picture error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW8JS.png

## Update

I solved the problem by using the library pyvips and saving as bmp. No idea why this suddenly works and I can open the file (which is still bigger than 2G)

```
import pyvips
vips_image = pyvips.Image.new_from_memory(combined_image_UV.data, 
combined_image_UV.shape[1], combined_image_UV.shape[0], bands=3, 
format="uchar")

vips_image.write_to_file("image.bmp")
```

Comment: You could tell us the dimensions and `dtype` of the Numpy array and show your code and the exact error message. Please do the SO tour and ensure your question has a *"Complete, Minimal and Reproducible Example"* of code in it. Thank you.

Comment: Please also use the internationally agreed SI units. `G` is used for `giga` and `B` for bytes  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte On the other hand, `b` is used for `bits`.

Comment: What is your system free memory status? Is it abouve 2GB ?

Comment: You still didn't specify the `dtype` of your array or its dimensions just prior to saving.

Comment: Are you maybe running on 32-bit Windows? And/or without installing `libtiff` which means you don't have support for BigTIFF which allows offsets exceeding 32-bits?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be loading all the parts you want into an enormous list which you then concatenate into an array which you then save as an image, which means you are trying to hold everything in a list and an array and an image at the same time thereby requiring 3x the RAM you might otherwise need.

Try creating your output image at the start, outside the loop then grab one piece at a time and paste it into the right place in the output image then move on to the next ROI without accumulating everything in memory except the output image.

You might also try adding `compression='lzw'` when saving your output file if you have `libtiff` installed.

Comment: Thanks Mark, yes I agree it's inefficient and one should try to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633988/how-can-i-save-a-huge-image-with-pil - However, it should not be the source of the problem, since I can save another array like this (that is 400mb smaller?) ? Will try the compression method, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved the problem by using pyvips and saving as bmp. No idea why that worked though.